# DomSanitizer in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am bit confused about DomSanitizer of Angular.
As far as I read it should strip away all the html tags from the input.
But Please check the stackblitz attached it doesnt remove all the tags.
Am I doing something wrong?
[text](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ivy-vycyzp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,node_modules%2F%40angular%2Fcore%2Fcore.d.ts)

I checked few blog posts online and tried following the same. But it doesnt mention what exact output to expect and its not giving me the output I was expecting.

Comment: It won't strip away *all* the html tags, just tags and attributes relevant to XSS since the purpose of the sanitizer is to mitigate cross site scripting attacks, it's not to remove html tags from a string.